# awk matching back slash in string

Tags: regex, awk

I have file contents below:

1. 2023-12-24T07:00:00 2152  4078  information.cp 253  TEST  Verifying certificate completed for 'C:\Windows\Temp\test file1.exe', SHA1: 'efdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754ee' lookup took: '57969' nanoseconds,
2. 2023-12-24T08:00:00 2152  4078  information.cp 253  TEST  Verifying certificate completed for 'C:\Microsoft\testfile2.exe', SHA1: 'ffdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754dd' lookup took: '57970' nanoseconds,

I am looking to print file path and SHA1 only if file path contains Microsoft OR Windows\Temp. So used below command:

`awk -F\' '($2 ~ (Microsoft || Windows\\Temp) {print $2, $4}' file`

But looks like awk does not like "\"

awk: syntax error at source line 1
context is
$2 ~ (Microsoft || >>>  Windows\ <<< \Temp) {print $2, $4}
awk: bailing out at source line 1

Kindly help

Comment: Check this out: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Usage.html Not my downvote, btw.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and then format all of your input, output, and code as Code Blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Backslashes need to be escaped => `\\`
2. The `or` condition requires
   you to state the `~` match operator for each condition
3. Regular expressions need to be enclosed in `/`

This is how it should look like to make it work:

```
awk -F\' '($2 ~ /Microsoft/ || $2 ~ /Windows\\Temp/) {print $2, $4}' file
```

Or just:

```
awk -F\' '($2 ~ /Microsoft|Windows\\Temp/) {print $2, $4}' file
```

since the or condition could be embedded in the regular expression as well.